# How should I set my DATABASE_URL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm working on my first-ever Heroku/Django app. I just want to be sure I'm setting my `DATABASE_URL` and `DATABASES` variables correctly. Here's what's in my code:

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql:///my_app'

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)
}
```

When I just have `DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()` and I try to use Django commands like `run server` or `migrate` I get the following error: `NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined`. I set the `DATABASE_URL` since doing so appears to solve this issue (after I create the `my_app` database).

Everything appears to be working fine as I code and test, but I've also seen a half-dozen different ways to set the database variables on the internet. If this isn't correct, I'd like to fix it now. The thing that really confuses me is, when I push my app to Heroku, how will the data get pushed to the web, when the database is /usr/local/var/postgres? Or will this not happen at all? Am I just too confused/tired at this point?

Comment: `DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()` returns NameError because DATABASES dictionary is not present there.  
    `DATABASES = {}`
    `DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()`  
should work

Comment: I already had a Postgresql database connected while tunning in localhost, but when I hosted on Heroku it created its own database, I need to change that and link my already existing database. How to do that, Can anyone help me with this?? Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is documented on [Heroku Devecenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#settings-py-changes)

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
# DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
#updated
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user:pass@localhost/dbname')}
```

If you need [Database connection pooling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#database-connection-pooling) add this bits too. [More details](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections)

```
# Enable Connection Pooling
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'
```

Comment: So when I just have `DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()` and I try to use Django commands like `runserver` or `migrate` I get the following error: `NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined`. I set the DATABASE_URL since doing so appears to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple matter of logic. You can't set the "default" key of the DATABASES dictionary before you have defined the dictionary itself.

Whether or not you set the `default` *parameter* to `dj_database_url` inside the call or as a separate `DATABASE_URL` variable is irrelevant, especially as that won't even be used on Heroku as it will be overridden by environment variables.

Comment: Right. I forgot that I deleted the original declaration of DATABASES. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @daniel, how to specify test database using dj_database_url ?

Answer (score 2):

This allows you to use any database settings during development,
but at production (on Heroku), `DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)` changes the database settings to the one created by Heroku.

```
import dj_database_url


DATABASES = {
    '"default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
    }
}


db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

You could use any database settings, but the last two lines allow heroku to create its own database for you.